# Constraint Layout. Render problems. Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-editor

I am everyday facing with very frustrating issue of ConstraintLayout in my project.

Project gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    ext.support_library_version = '27.0.2'
    ext.play_services_version = '11.6.2'
    ext.firebase_version = '11.6.2'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'

        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

This is my short version of app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

// set to 'cmake', 'none'
def nativeBuildSystem = 'none'//'cmake'

realm {
    syncEnabled = false
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 27
        compileSdkVersion 27
        minSdkVersion 21
        // for using vectors for less than 21 API
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        versionCode 56
        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.6.5"

        renderscriptTargetApi 2
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true    // Enable RS support

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    /*********************************  Deep Linking Library *********************************************/
    api 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch:3.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch-processor:3.1.1'

    /*********************************    Android SDK  *********************************************/
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_library_version"
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    api "com.android.support:percent:$support_library_version"
    api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_library_version"
    api "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$support_library_version"
    api "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_library_version"
    api "com.android.support:design:$support_library_version"
    api "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$support_library_version"
    api "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$support_library_version"
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

}
```

Below what i see in Layout Editor:

[image]

Below my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Layout Editor in this case says:

[image]

And if i click on **Show Exception** i will see:

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
at android.support.constraint.R$styleable.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:440)
at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:420)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:211)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:547)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:681)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried a lot in order to solve it but without success. I doesn't solved using simple approaches like invalidate cache/clean project/rebuild project and etc...

Comment: show us your java code and xml

Comment: it's blank layout which root is Constraint layout without children at all

Comment: show your xml code not preview

Comment: please add your app gradle file.

Comment: For the other two AppCompatImageView and AppCompatTextView you have to change your "parent" Theme from "Theme.AppCompat....." to "Base.Theme.AppCompat..."! Build and Refresh and this two problems are gone.

Same on my side, but I still have the problem with ConstraintLayout :-(

Comment: @Vladislav: Do you get also the same error if you use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar? I get on this also "NegativeArraySizeException"!

Comment: @chrisonline yeah, you are right. If i change the theme, issues with AppCompatTextView and AppCompatImageView are really gone. And yes, issue with ConstraintLayout still exists... 
I really don't know what to do, i ended up with doing all layout work in another test project... It sounds crazy, but for now i don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Vladislav: Have you seen my solution? Does it also work on your side this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**
It seems the Layout Editor has some troubles if you have **too much** attributes in one `<declare-stylable>` tag defined in your **attr.xml**!

**Solution:**
I have **49** attributes in one `<declare-stylable>` tag.
If I remove **4** attributes, so I have **45**, the Layout Editor is working.

I have also added an Issue on the Google Issue Tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71641021

**UPDATE from Google Issue:**
This has been fixed for the Android Studio 3.1 release.

Comment: Yes!! I had like more than 100 attr in 1 <declare-stylable> Thanks a lot. It does work, eventually!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `ConstraintLayout` but rather go for `Relative...` or `Linear...`. That should work.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant to my question at all. If you'd looked at my question in more accurate way, you would have understood what i meant.